# WPML - Filter by individual or all languages

Tags: plugin-wpml

I have a query based on two parameters on a multilingual website (with WPML). To simplify, let's say that one of my filter is the language of the post to retrieve : English, French or all languages. English and French are working fine but I can't make the "all languages" filter work.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// First I get the "lang" Get value
$langGet = get_query_var('lang', ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);
?>

/* Then  have my form to filter posts */
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink( get_the_ID() ); ?>" method="get">
    <label for="lang"><?php _e( 'Languages', 'mytextdomain' ); ?></label>
    <?php
    $languages = apply_filters( 'wpml_active_languages', NULL );
    if($languages) { ?>
        <select name="lang">
            <?php foreach($languages as $language) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $language['language_code']; ?>" <?php echo ( $langGet == $language['language_code'] ) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $language['translated_name']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <option value="all" <?php echo ( $langGet == 'all' ) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php _e('All languages', 'mytextdomain'); ?></option>
        </select>
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Filter projects', 'mytextdomain' ); ?>">
</form>

<?php
// Then I set up the switch for current language
if($langGet != 'all') {
    global $sitepress;
    $current_lang = $sitepress->get_current_language();
    $sitepress->switch_lang($langGet, true);
}

// Then I define my query
// Here is the line that is supposed to show all languages but it's not working.
$filters = ( $langGet == 'all' ) ? true : false;

$taxId = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', 755, 'project_category' );

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 16,
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'project_category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $taxId,
        )
    ),
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'suppress_filters' => $filters
);
$projects = new WP_Query($args);
```

But this is not showing all languages. Moreover I noticed that a `#038;lang=all` gets added at the end of my url when I am on page 2.

Can someone help me on this?
Thanks!

Comment: Downvoting a question without explanation...what's the point guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've made it work. The problem was not with the filter but with tax query. Here is the solution for those who might be interested.

```
<?php
// I check the lang query var if it's empty we'll display all languages
$langGet = get_query_var('lang', 'all');
?>

/* Then  have my form to filter posts */
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink( get_the_ID() ); ?>" method="get">
    <label for="lang"><?php _e( 'Languages', 'mytextdomain' ); ?></label>
    <?php
    $languages = apply_filters( 'wpml_active_languages', NULL );
    if($languages) { ?>
        <select name="lang">
            <?php foreach($languages as $language) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $language['language_code']; ?>" <?php echo ( $langGet == $language['language_code'] ) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $language['translated_name']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <option value="all" <?php echo ( $langGet == 'all' ) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php _e('All languages', 'mytextdomain'); ?></option>
        </select>
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Filter projects', 'mytextdomain' ); ?>">
</form>

<?php
// Then I set up the switch for current language
if( $langGet != 'all' ) {
    global $sitepress;
    $current_lang = $sitepress->get_current_language();
    $sitepress->switch_lang($langGet, true);
    $taxTerms = array( apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', 755, 'project_category' ) );
    $filters = false;
} else {
    // If we want to display all languages we have to remove filters
    global $sitepress;
    remove_filter( 'get_terms_args', array( $sitepress, 'get_terms_args_filter' ), 10 );
    remove_filter( 'get_term', array( $sitepress, 'get_term_adjust_id' ), 1 );
    remove_filter( 'terms_clauses', array( $sitepress, 'terms_clauses' ), 10 );
    $taxTerms = array( 755, 776, 777, 778 );
    $filters = true;
}

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;

// Then we set the query
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $postsperpage,
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'project_category',
          'field' => 'term_id',
          'terms' => $taxTerms
      )
    ),
    'orderby'   => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'meta_key' => $metakey,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'suppress_filters' => $filters
);
$projects = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this article from wpml

https://wpml.org/forums/topic/problems-to-show-in-all-languages-suppress_filters-true-not-working/

Comment: Thanks but I have already seen this post and this doesn't solve my issue.